# How to write Condition Statement for Date validation in java validation

Tags: java, validation

I'm working on the java project using Struts2 where `currentDate` is the Today  Date and  `fromDate` is User Entering `Date.fromDate` date should be equal or future from the `currentDate` .I write the code for Future Date ,how to write the Condition ***fromDate should be equal to currentDate***.

```
if(!(fromDate.after(currentDate))){
    addFieldError("fromDate","The date is Older");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> fromDate date should be equal or future from the currentDate.
>
> how to write the Condition fromDate < = CurrentDate.

Both of your statement written above clashes with each other. In your wording you are saying `fromDate>=currentDate` but when you put `fromDate < = CurrentDate` you are telling `fromDate` should be before or equal to `currentDate`,

As per your comment below, you should use

```
 if(fromDate.before(currentDate)){
    addFieldError("fromDate","The from date should be future date");
 }
```

Comment: I am using this validation in ticket Resservation System.In this case  fromDate or toDate should not be less currentDate because in older date we will not to reserve the tickets.so,fromDate date should be equal or future from the currentDate.@Sanket D

Comment: check now...updated my answer...you can replace the text in error per what you want

Comment: Your Answer Code  and My code are given same Answer.It Shows The Error when we Give Date before currentDate and  fromDate=CurrentDate. but in my Condition statement i required **fromDate date should be equal or future from the currentDate**.